# Something wrong with ajax call, cannot figure out what

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to make a simple ajax call but I'm not able to `console.log` the response.
Navigating to the url in browser gives back data, but still.

I'm not seeing the error alert either, so it should not be failing?

Code:

```
var $searchBox = $('#search');
var $searchButton = $('#button');

$searchButton.on('click', function(){

var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="
+ $searchBox.val() + "&format=json&callback=?";
console.log(url);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(errorMessage){
        alert('Error');
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/taef1rkf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent click default redirection, you can use `e.preventDefault()` event.

```
var $searchBox = $('#search');
var $searchButton = $('#button');

$searchButton.on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); 
   var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="
+ $searchBox.val() + "&format=json&callback=?";
   console.log(url);
   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: url,
     async: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(errorMessage){
        alert('Error');
     }
   });
});
```